# Create a virtual input device that loops back audio output, if Stereo Mix is unavailable?

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, loopback

I want to use Friture to analyze the audio from my speakers (while working on sound synthesis).

I have seen tutorials mentioning Stereo Mix, but as I don't have the Realtek Audio Driver, this is unavailable for me.

Is there an easy way to simulate an input device that simply feeds back the output of my speakers to other applications?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the method I found for this, after searching the web for about half an hour.

[VB audio cable](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/) gives you two new audio devices: CABLE output, a recording device; and CABLE input, an playback device.

Once installed, simply set CABLE input as your default output device. You can do this via the Windows Sounds dialog (right click the speaker in the taskbar, click Sounds, go to the Playback tab).

Then open the properties dialog for CABLE output (in the Recording tab) and tick 'Listen to this device' in the Listen tab. Set the output in this dialog to the speaker you want your audio to actually come out of.

Your audio should work normally, but now you can select CABLE output in applications that require an input device (for recording, analysis etc) and the audio output from your computer will be routed to this device.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.